# Why does Devise [DELETE] method fail when used to sign_out (but not for destroy) via iOS Add Home Screen?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise

So, for anyone who is actually encountering the same problem, I have a solution (see below).

But **my question is 'What is causing this to happen?'** Why does the Devise **:delete** method fail for sign_out (but the **:destroy** method works)

*Pre-applying solution: fail on sign_out (via :delete method)*

```
web_1  | Started POST "/logout" for 172.25.0.1 at 2020-01-16 09:28:44 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.25.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  |
web_1  | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/logout"):
web_1  |
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web_1  | web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web_1  | web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web_1  | web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web_1  | web-console (3.6.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
web_1  | railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
web_1  | railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:28:in `call'
web_1  | sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
web_1  | rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
web_1  | rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
web_1  | activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
web_1  | actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
web_1  | rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
web_1  | railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
web_1  | puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
web_1  | puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
web_1  | puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
web_1  | puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
web_1  | puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

*Pre-applying solution: success on destroy end_user (via :delete method)*

```
web_1  | Started DELETE "/end_user" for 172.25.0.1 at 2020-01-16 09:20:01 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.25.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | Processing by EndUsers::RegistrationsController#destroy as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ycapv7HYDWdWNsG/Aqdpm+mqWG4CImp6bKOrzjRW1+jdbccoMvspCuo35NVNHPrZs0WN8BxFvVAEu9wBostcog==", "end_user"=>{"current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
web_1  |   EndUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `end_users`.* FROM `end_users` WHERE `end_users`.`id` = 71 ORDER BY `end_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
web_1  |   EndUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `end_users`.* FROM `end_users` WHERE `end_users`.`id` = 71 LIMIT 1
web_1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
web_1  |   EuPhoneNumber Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `eu_phone_numbers`.* FROM `eu_phone_numbers` WHERE `eu_phone_numbers`.`end_user_id` = 71
web_1  |   EuEmailAddress Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `eu_email_addresses`.* FROM `eu_email_addresses` WHERE `eu_email_addresses`.`end_user_id` = 71
web_1  |   EuAddress Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `eu_addresses`.* FROM `eu_addresses` WHERE `eu_addresses`.`end_user_id` = 71
web_1  |   EndUser Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `end_users` WHERE `end_users`.`id` = 71
web_1  |    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
web_1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `active_storage_attachments`.* FROM `active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`record_id` = 71 AND `active_storage_attachments`.`record_type` = 'EndUser' AND `active_storage_attachments`.`name` = 'profile_pic' LIMIT 1
web_1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
web_1  | Completed 302 Found in 119ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

*Routes*

```
                        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
          new_end_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                                                                         end_users/sessions#new
              end_user_session POST   /login(.:format)                                                                         end_users/sessions#create
      destroy_end_user_session POST   /logout(.:format)                                                                        end_users/sessions#destroy
         new_end_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)                                                                  end_users/passwords#new
        edit_end_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                                                                 end_users/passwords#edit
             end_user_password PATCH  /password(.:format)                                                                      end_users/passwords#update
                               PUT    /password(.:format)                                                                      end_users/passwords#update
                               POST   /password(.:format)                                                                      end_users/passwords#create
  cancel_end_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)                                                                        end_users/registrations#cancel
     new_end_user_registration GET    /sign_up(.:format)                                                                       end_users/registrations#new
    edit_end_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)                                                                          end_users/registrations#edit
         end_user_registration PATCH  /                                                                                        end_users/registrations#update
                               PUT    /                                                                                        end_users/registrations#update
                               DELETE /                                                                                        end_users/registrations#destroy
                               POST   /                                                                                        end_users/registrations#create
             end_user_settings GET    /settings(.:format)                                                                      end_users/registrations#edit
         end_user_settings_tab GET    /settings/:tab(.:format)                                                                 end_users/registrations#edit
             end_user_register GET    /register(.:format)                                                                      end_users/sessions#new
              destroy_end_user DELETE /end_user(.:format)                                                                      end_users/registrations#destroy
      end_user_update_password PUT    /updatepassword(.:format)                                                                end_users/registrations#updatepassword
                  registration POST   /register(.:format)                                                                      end_users/registrations#create
              new_user_session GET    /app/login(.:format)                                                                     users/sessions#new
                  user_session POST   /app/login(.:format)                                                                     users/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session POST   /app/logout(.:format)                                                                    users/sessions#destroy
             new_user_password GET    /app/password/new(.:format)                                                              users/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET    /app/password/edit(.:format)                                                             users/passwords#edit
                 user_password PATCH  /app/password(.:format)                                                                  users/passwords#update
                               PUT    /app/password(.:format)                                                                  users/passwords#update
                               POST   /app/password(.:format)                                                                  users/passwords#create
      cancel_user_registration GET    /app/cancel(.:format)                                                                    users/registrations#cancel
         new_user_registration GET    /app/sign_up(.:format)                                                                   users/registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET    /app/edit(.:format)                                                                      users/registrations#edit
             user_registration PATCH  /app(.:format)                                                                           users/registrations#update
                               PUT    /app(.:format)                                                                           **users/registrations#update
                               DELETE /app(.:format)                                                                           users/registrations#destroy**
                               POST   /app(.:format)                                                                           users/registrations#create
                 user_settings GET    /app/settings(.:format)                                                                  users/registrations#edit
             user_settings_tab GET    /app/settings/:tab(.:format)                                                             users/registrations#edit
          user_update_password PUT    /app/updatepassword(.:format)                                                            users/registrations#updatepassword
```

Devise version

```
  * devise (4.4.3)
```

Rails version

```
  * rails (5.2.0)
```

**The solution:** 
Change the sign_out method via the *devise.rb* file found in the *config/initializers* folder.

```
   # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
-  config.sign_out_via = :delete
+  # config.sign_out_via = :delete
+  config.sign_out_via = :post
```

Then where you have links to sign_out you need to replace them with buttons,
replacing link_to with button_to:

```
-                <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_end_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => "dropdown-item") %>
+                <%= button_to('Logout', destroy_end_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => "dropdown-item hasaction") %>
```

or pure html (adding a CSRF token if necessary):

```
-                        <a href="/app/logout" data-method='delete'>
-                            <i className="fas fa-sign-out"></i>
-                            <span className="nav-label">Logout</span>
-                        </a>
+                        <form action="/app/logout" method="post">
+                            <button type="submit" className="btn-plain text-left hasaction">
+                                <i className="fas fa-sign-out"></i>
+                                <span className="nav-label">Logout</span>
+                                <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value={this.state.csrf_token} />
+                            </button>
+                        </form>
```

**Note:** in the routes above, the solution has so far only been applied to the sign_out method